# How do I route to a new layout using useLocation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a basic knowledge of React yet and i've barely used some features. I have 2 layouts, I want to be able to click on a sidebar option to route to the new layout.

```
function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        {/* <InnerPage/> */}
        <Header open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
        <Sidebar open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Overview} />
          <Route exact path="/overview" component={Overview} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

I have a sidebar option "main" that onclick it should lead to the entire new layout. Please, How I implement this using useLocation or maybe any other suitable way.

Comment: Why showing `Overview` component for both routes you have ?

Comment: could you elaborate on "main"? what and where is it?

Comment: @Tony check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jnwkuw?file=src/Layout1.jsx), I made a simple example, you can get a basic idea from this

Comment: You can simply use the `Link` Component that should be available right?